# ownProps is missing props added through mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following form:

```
let NoteForm = ({handleSave}) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSave}>
      <Field component="input" type="text" name="body" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

And:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    isNew: state.isNew
  }
}
```

And finally:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    handleSave: () => {
      dispatch(saveNote(ownProps)) // ownProps does not contain "isNew" prop
    }
  }
}
```

The prop `isNew` is not included in `ownProps`. I hope it's an obvious mistake I am making here and unable to see it.

The component that renders `NoteForm` is `Note` and renders it conditionally as such:

`{ (isNew || isEdit) && <NoteForm /> }`

I can certainly pass the props in as attributes, but at this point I am stubborn as I am unable to understand why my prop is missing. I have already tried passing it in as an argument to my component as such: `{handleSave, isNew}` but that doesn't work either.

For reference, my connect is:

```
NoteForm = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(NoteForm);
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently I can't test this, but it makes sense that `ownProps` are the properties that are passed to the component that is being returned by `connect(...)(YourComponent)`. On the other hand `isNew` is passed directly to `YourComponent` by `mapStateToProps`, so you wouldn't have access to it in the `mapDispatchToProps` callback.

Somewhere in your app...

```
const ReturnedComponent = connect(...)(YourComponent)

render () {

  <ReturnedComponent {...ownProps} />
}
```

These `ownProps` are accessible by `mapStateToProps`, but not the ones passed by `mapDispatchToProps`.

---

See a possible solution to your problem [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/237) recommended by the creator of redux himself.

Comment: But ``connect`` takes in ``mapStateToProps`` and ``mapDispatchToProps`` which is why I am still confused about why it is that ``ownProps`` doesn't include the property. I updated my answer.

Comment: ownProps are *not* the props of the component wrapped by connect, but the props passed to the returned component from connect(..). There is a difference. The first one is a level deeper thus receives more properties.